# Red Local con ip fija

Tags: redes, internet, lan

estoy trando de resolver un pequeño problema que se me ha hecho complejo: como contexto en el lugar donde trabajo existe una red del tipo: 10.x.x.x, todos los dispositivos tienen una ip fija de esa red asignados, ahora bien, en una oficina especial tengo un router inalambrico A que levanta una señal wifi y a los clientes les asigna ip dinamicas (sin embargo puedo accede a cualquier equipo de la red 10), este router tiene configurada una ip fija del segmento 10 y se conecta por la boca WAN del router, esto esta bien y funciona como se pidio, ahora viene mi problema: tengo que levantar otra red pero en esta nueva red, a diferencia de la otra, los terminales deben estar conectados mediante una ip estatica, entonces desde el router A se saco un cable de red hacia la otra oficina y se conecta a una puerta LAN del router B, si conecto un cable a este nuevo router me da conectividad pero sin asignarle ip al adaptador, mas si le configuro una ip 10.x.x.x no  tiene salida a internet...

Al router B tambien se le configuro una ip estatica en la WAN, pero la conexion entre ambos routers es entre los puertos lan...

Saludos a todos espero me puedan dar una orientacion de que me puedo estar saltando

Comment: Esto es un problema de configuración de red y no un problema de programación, tal como lo establece el [help/on-topic]

Comment: Sería de muy buena ayuda que incluyeras un gráfico en tú preguntas para hacernos una representación de lo que quieres lograr, de seguro todo se resuelve con armar algunas reglas de ruteo